# Python 2.7.14 on Raspbian

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian

My client has an application developed on python2.7.14, and I'm trying to run it on a raspberry.
When I run it on python2.7.9 it has some interface problems, so I installed python2.7.14 exactly as said in this link: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/

Now, when I run the application on python2.7.14 it says that I don't have module RPi.GPIO and PIL, and when I try to install/update it says it's already installed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well you should maybe have followed instructions on how to install Python on Raspbian instead of Ubuntu/LinuxMint :D? Anyway, could you show the commands you are using to install the missing modules, and their output?

Comment: Where is your Python 2.7.14 executable? Try to install the modules with `sudo /path/to/your/python2.7.14 -m pip install RPi.GPIO Pillows`.

Comment: I wasn't luck googling "python2.7.14" and "raspbian".
Commands:
pip install RPi.GPIO
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
return: 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): RPi.GPIO in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
When i run the python program:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO

Comment: You need to install the modules with the same version of Python that you are using to run the program. See my previous comment.

Comment: Command1: sudo /usr/src/Python-2.7.14 -m pip install RPi.GPIO Pillows
Return1: sudo: /usr/src/Python-2.7.14: command not found
Command2: sudo: /usr/src/Python-2.7.14/python -m pip install RPi.GPIO Pillows
Return2: /usr/src/Python-2.7.14/python: No module named pip

Comment: Maybe you could try with `pyenv`: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. Install it, then run `pyenv install 2.7.14`, then `pyenv shell 2.7.14`, then `pip install ...`, then `python your_prog.py`.

Comment: pyenv install 2.7.14
Downloading Python-2.7.14.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tar.xz
Installing Python-2.7.14...
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
WARNING: The Python bz2 extension was not compiled. Missing the bzip2 lib?
WARNING: The Python sqlite3 extension was not compiled. Missing the SQLite3 lib?
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem...

Comment: Please consult the wiki page to solve the problem ;) You have to install the missing libs to be able to compile Python. I know it's tedious but this is how it's done. Try, fix error, try again, fix new error, etc. Success.